# Cannot access Windows 7 folder shares from OSX

Tags: macos, network, windows

I have a persistent problem where my MacBook Pro cannot access the folder shares on my Windows 7 computer using smb://[server name] at seemingly random occurrences.

I am able to access the shares perfectly fine, copy items to and from the share with no issues, then once my MacBook Pro goes to sleep or is disconnected from the network it cannot access the share anymore, with the error "There was a problem connecting to the server [server name]".  It seems to come back after I do a few restarts of the Windows 7 computers and the MacBook Pro.

When it gets to this state I can still ping the computer via IP address but cannot connect via IP address.  I can also connect using the MS Remote Desktop but not using others like CORD.

Is there a way to sort this out so I don't have to restart every computer in the house to get them to talk to each other?

I know it is not an issue with the Windows 7 computer, as other Windows computers talk to is perfectly fine, and it is not a firewall issue or anything like that.  It is something to do with how OSX handles smb connections especially after sleeping or network disconnection.